# How can I obtain a control's Handle in a ASP.NET VB project?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I want to add Cue/Watermarks to my ASP:TextBox controls for a nicer user experience, and came across the very nice CueProvider, which has [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/503482/CueProvider) VB-adjusted version which sadly I cannot compile.

My class is as follows

```
#Region "Imports"
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
#End Region

Public Class Watermark

<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
Private Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As HandleRef,
                                    ByVal Msg As UInteger,
                                    ByVal wParam As IntPtr,
                                    ByVal lParam As String) As IntPtr
End Function

Public Shared Sub [Set](ByVal ctl As Control, ByVal hintText As String)

    Const EM_SETCUEBANNER As Int32 = &H1501

    Dim retainOnFocus As IntPtr = New IntPtr(1)
    Dim msg As Int32 = EM_SETCUEBANNER

    SendMessage(New HandleRef(ctl, ctl.Handle), msg, retainOnFocus, hintText)

End Sub

End Class
```

The compile failure is on the `New HandleRef(ctl, ctl.Handle)` that second parameter is apparently not a valid property.

How I can get the windows handle of the incoming UI control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have found is for Windows Forms, but you are developing an ASP.NET Web Forms application. Therefore it is not appropriate. You cannot obtain a window handle in ASP.NET.

I believe what you're after is a placeholder.

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="First Name" />
```

Or if you need a server control,

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" placeholder="First Name" />
```

Comment: Excellent, that is what I should have been doing. Much appreciated, thanks!